# Vulkan : How could queues support different features? / VkQueue implementation

Tags: gpu, vulkan

In my understanding, VkPhysicalDevice represents an implementation of Vulkan, which could be represented as a GPU and its drivers.
We are supposed to record commands with VkCommandBuffers and send them through queues to, potentially, multithread the work we send to the gpu.
That is why I understand the fact there can be multiple queues.
I understand as well that QueueFamilies groups queues depending on the features they can do (the extensions available for them e.g. presentation, as well as graphics computations, transfer, etc).

However, if a GPU is able to do Graphics work, why are there queues unable to do so?
I heard that using queues with less features could be faster, but why?
What is a queue concretely?
Is it only tied to vulkan implementation? Or is it related to hardware specific things?

I just don't understand why queues with different features exist, and even after searching through the Vulkan doc, StackOverflow, vulkan-tutorial and vkguide, the only thing I found was "Queues in Vulkan are an “execution port” for GPUs.", which I don't really understand and on which I can't find anything on google.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: "*VkPhysicalDevice represents an implementation of Vulkan*" No, it represents a physical device, an actual piece of hardware. `VkDevice` represents an implementation of Vulkan which is associated with one (or more) physical devices.

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDevice.html
The documentation says "A physical device usually represents a single complete implementation of Vulkan", am I missing something?
What piece of hardware would it represent if not? A GPU?
Any ideas about queues?

Comment: That's not exactly a good explanation of physical devices, since you can create a single logical device from *multiple* physical devices (for SLI and the like).

Comment: I just looked into it,
So that's why the "usually" is here, thank you!
It seems like you know a lot of stuff about graphics programming, any ideas about why queues with different features exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A queue is a thing that consumes and executes commands, such that each queue (theoretically) executes separately from every other queue. You can think of a queue as a mouth, with commands as food.

Queues within a queue family typically execute commands using the same underlying hardware to process them. This would be like a creature with multiple mouths but all of them connect to the same digestive tract. How much food they can eat is separate from how much food they can *digest*. Food eaten by one mouth may have to wait for food previously eaten by another to pass through the digestive tract.

Queues from different families may (or may not) have distinct underlying execution hardware. This would be like a creature with multiple mouths and multiple digestive tracts. If a mouth eats, that food need not wait for food from a different mouth to digest.

Of course, distinct underlying execution hardware is typically distinct for a reason. Several GPUs have specialized DMA hardware for doing copies to/from device-local memory. Such hardware will typically expose a queue family that only allows transfer operations, and those transfer operations may be restricted in their byte alignment compared to transfers done on graphics-capable queues.

Note that these are general rules. Sometimes queues within a family do execute on different hardware, and sometimes queues between families use much of the same hardware. The API and implementations don't always make this clear, so you may have to benchmark different circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply!
The explanation about queues is nice, and the thing about specialized DMA hardware sounds to answer my question :)
However, in the case of a queue supporting graphics operations and not compute, or vice versa, what is it due to? Specialized DMA hardware again? Or is it only theoretical and doesn't serve any practicall purpose?

Comment: @Progz: "*in the case of a queue supporting graphics operations and not compute*" Well, that's not allowed. If a queue supports graphics, you can also dispatch compute operations on it too. As to whether there is any particular purpose to compute-only queues, that's up to the individual hardware. Vulkan simply provides a way to expose what the implementation wants to expose. You should pick the queue that is most specialized to the task at hand, unless you want easier synchronization between different operations.